# Do events bubble up to window in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm binding a simple click event to the `window` object but the handler doesn't get called in IE8 (works on Chrome and FF):

```
$(window).click(function (e) {
  alert('Hello there! I\'m in the window.click hanlder!');
});
```

Anyone why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that IE (testing IE8) doesn't bubble events to the `window`.

Here's an example ( http://jsfiddle.net/SZXrn/8/ ):

```
if (window.attachEvent) // IE
{
  window.attachEvent('onclick', function () {
      alert("Yay window obj was clicked! IE");
  });

  document.attachEvent('onclick', function () {
      alert("Yay document obj was clicked! IE");
  });
}
else if (window.addEventListener) // Other
{
  window.addEventListener('click', function () {
      alert("Yay window obj was clicked! Non-IE");
  });

  document.addEventListener('click', function () {
      alert("Yay document obj was clicked! Non-IE");
  });  
}
```

So, the solution is to bind to the `document` instead of `window`.